# does android ndk accelerates hardware?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.2

I am developing an android app that processes images. I tried android ndk before so i can code natively to speed up performance. But I discontinued using it because I can't fully understand the C language.

So I continue my app dev using Java code. I searched for easier and better solution to speed up the performance of my app without using native code and it was a success.

After sometime, i realized that the ndk wasn't remove from my project. I removed it and recompile my code so i can remove the cpp folder too. But when I test my app, it became very slowwwwww... I linked the ndk again and now the image processing is fast again.

My question is, how did that happen???

Comment: You should post [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

For processing images, usually C/C++ gives better image output than Java in desktop.

While programming in Android also i saw C/C++ Android NDK code gives better image output and faster than Android Java code.

This may be because of **C/C++ code directly complies to native code** where else java compiles to byte code and from byte code complies to native code by JNI.

And in NDK, **.so** files are created by Application Binary Interface(ABI) by that application machine code is directly interacted with the system at run time.